# IDE Error Android Studio 3.1.2 "Waiting for build to finish

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello Stack i receive the following error:

> null
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.getRenderResult(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:602)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenViewBase.getResult(ScreenViewBase.java:109)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenView.getResult(ScreenView.java:30)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.menu.NavigationViewSceneView.getPreferredSize(NavigationViewSceneView.java:64)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.SceneView.getPreferredSize(SceneView.java:95)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.createSceneViewsForMenu(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:265)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.doCreateSceneView(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:234)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.createSceneView(SceneManager.java:73)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.(SceneManager.java:66)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:157)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.NlDesignSurface.createSceneManager(NlDesignSurface.java:145)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.DesignSurface.setModel(DesignSurface.java:281)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.initNeleModelOnEventDispatchThread(NlEditorPanel.java:143)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.lambda$null$4(NlEditorPanel.java:139)
>         at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.lambda$smartInvokeLater$7(DumbServiceImpl.java:366)
>         at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
>         at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
>         at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
>         at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
>         at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
>         at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
>         at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

I use the following view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="Hoofdmenu" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
            android:title="Uitloggen" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery"
            android:visible="false" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow"
            android:visible="false" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools"
            android:visible="false" />
    </group>

    <item
        android:title="Communicate"
        android:visible="false">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

After updating my IDE to 3.1.2 i now receive this error on my main_drawer activity

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Apparently the line

```
tools:showIn="navigation_view"
```

Crashes the preview

Comment: @KenWhite The error seems IDE related

Comment: Your edit solve the problem